# Solvable number fields

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

I think that unsolvability of the general quintic and higher degree polynomial equations by radicals is really cute, but also a little bit of a shame. I mean wouldn't it be nice if they were all solvable. Though formulas would be horrible looking like for the quartic, so may be not a bad thing after all.

Anyway I am wondering if there are concrete examples of number fields in which every polynomial equation has a solution by radicals.

Am I right in thinking that the algebraic closure of this kind of a field will have a solvable group as its Galois group over the field? In that case it'd need to be a solvable subgroup of the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$ whose quotient is a finite group? Are there any known examples of these, or do they not exist, or it's something else?

Comment: That's why we often treat algebraic number theory in $p$-adic numbers, because the absolute Galois group of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ is solvable. The same holds for any field complete for a discrete valuation (such as $\Bbb{C}((t))$). For the finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$, none has this property.

Comment: @reuns, yes that's the nice thing about p-adics. I am asking about number fields. Are you implying that there aren't any?

Comment: @reuns, how does the proof of "no number field has this property" go?

Comment: Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n$ over the rationals. Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, not solvable in radicals over the rationals, and of degree prime to $n$. Can $p$ be solvable in radicals over $K$?

Answer (score 7):

For a number field $K$ take

- $\mathfrak{p}_2,\mathfrak{p}_3,\mathfrak{p}_5$ some prime ideals above $2,3,5$,
- take $h_2\in O_K/\mathfrak{p}_2[x]$ monic irreducible of degree $4$,

  take $h_3\in O_K/\mathfrak{p}_3[x]$ monic irreducible of degree $3$,

  take $h_5\in O_K/\mathfrak{p}_5[x]$ monic irreducible of degree $5$,
- Take $f\in O_K[x]_{monic}$ of degree $5$ such that $$f\equiv x h_2\bmod \mathfrak{p}_2,f\equiv x^2 h_3\bmod \mathfrak{p}_3,f\equiv  h_5\bmod \mathfrak{p}_5$$

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$.

$O_L$ will contain a prime $\mathfrak{P}_2$ above $\mathfrak{p}_2$ and $f=xh_2\bmod \mathfrak{P}_2$ will split completely, so $$4\  | \ [O_L:\mathfrak{P}_2:O_K/\mathfrak{p}_2] \ \implies 4 \ | \ [L:K]$$

And so on, you'll get that $4\cdot 3\cdot 5$ divides $[L:K]$.

This implies that $Gal(L/K)$ is either $S_5$ or $A_5$, unsolvable.

Answer (score 2):

Number fields satisfy [Hilbert's irreducibility theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_irreducibility_theorem), which implies that there are infinitely many extensions with Galois group $S_n$ (the symmetric group, which is non-solvable for $n \geq 5$) for any $n$. Thus, there are infinitely many non-solvable quintic polynomials over any number field.